# Why does the following equality hold about $r$ component of laplace operator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am wondering why the following equality holds ?
$$\frac{1}{r^2} \frac {\partial}{\partial r}(r^2 \frac {\partial}{\partial r})= \frac {1}{r} \partial_r^2 r$$ . 
I tried making some substitutions but it doesn't seem to work . :(

Comment: For displayed equations, you need to put the punctuation inside the dollar signs (ideally spaced apart by `\;`), since, as you can see, otherwise it ends up on the following line.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of identity is proved simply by moving all derivatives through to the right by applying the product rule and then comparing:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{r^2}\def\fr{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}}\fr\left(r^2\fr\right)
&=
\frac1{r^2}\left(\fr r^2\right)\fr+\frac1{r^2}r^2\fr\fr
\\
&=
\frac2r\fr+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1r\fr\fr r
&=
\frac1r\fr\left(\fr r\right)+\frac1r\fr r\fr
\\
&=
\frac1r\fr+\frac1r\left(\fr r\right)\fr+\frac1rr\fr\fr
\\
&=
\frac2r\fr+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}\;.
\end{align}
$$